# Video is not displaying in android app

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

My android app (using phonegap), run a website. This website, have a Youtube playlist (API). On browser, the video works fine, but in the application is not displayed.

When my app is started, the user is redirected to website:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://website.com.br/midia" />
```

Video code:

```
<object width="90%" height="150">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/7hT7Uxywyso&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/7hT7Uxywyso&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="90%" height="150" wmode="transparent">
</object>
```

Comment: This plugin will help you to play a YouTube video in a Phonegap/Cordova app:
https://github.com/remcob00/cordova-phonegap_youtube_player_api_android

Comment: Thank you, looks like this plugin only "embed" a video, but I need display all videos from a specific channel (or specific playlist). Is that correct?

Comment: You use youtube json api to get all video from one Channel.